# Get location and contacts in LinkedIn OpenId

Tags: laravel, linkedin-api, laravel-socialite

I'm using LinkedIn Auth with OpenId on LinkedIn API Dev.
I've used Socialite in Laravel to get user information :
`return Socialite::driver('linkedin-openid')->scopes(['openid', 'profile'])->redirect();`

It works fine. But I don't get now how to get the location of the user, and his connections.
Whenever I try to add scopes or differents API routes from LinkedIn, it just ends in an error, as if those routes weren't usable anymore (parameter code not found, in return of error).

Any ideas ? Or it's not just possible anymore ?